# Where can I download Landsat 7 data as GeoTiff

Tags: open-data, satellites

I want to test a program for image classification that uses GeoTiff data with a separate file for each band. So I'm looking for some sample satellite data, preferably of Landsat 7, that doesn't need any further correction or pre-processing (I'm not familiar with these things and just want to do a brief testing) and can be used as is. It should be in separate GeoTiff files for each band, or there should be a way to separate them.

I already searched a lot in the web and found services like GloVis, LandsatLook Viewer or USGS Earth Explorer, but I simply don't know how to use this data, it seems to require pre-processing, which I have neither the skills for nor do I have the software for that.

Comment: In all the sites you mention you can get the images in GeoTiff (one file per band), no further processing needed. I could answer this with some steps, but this question should go to GIS SE.
Take into account that after 2003 Landsat 7 had the SLC-off, resulting in black stripes in most of the images. And also take into account that Landsat 8 data comes in 16-bits files, so no all image software will display it correctly without some level adjustments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might get better answers at [OpenData.SE], but please read carefully the guidelines for that site before asking there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what are you looking for, but based my own wild guess and hopefully you will be able to get your Landsat data (ready for analysis) from earth-science.
https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules?p=C1452914042-USGS_EROS&tl=1532843869!4!!&q=Landsat&ok=Landsat

cheers